# How to Embed Locally Hosted Bot in a Website?

Tags: asp.net, botframework

I have created a chat bot using Microsoft's Bot Framework and have tested it using the Bot Emulator. Now I want to integrate this chat bot into my website which is also hosted on local server. I have registered this bot on dev.botframework.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your bot is registered with Microsoft and running smoothly you can embed your bot into your website by following these steps:

1. Head to your bot on the Bot Portal where it should be if registered and click on the word **Edit** next to Web Chat.

[image]

2. Copy one of the secret keys and include it in the `<iframe>` **src value** that's in the Embed Code section.

[image]

3. Use this  within your website's HTML, etc... to display a chat window that allows users to interact with your bot.

[image]